# Есть написанное приложение под iOS на Swift, но есть нужда перевести его под Android. Как это можно сделать?

Tags: android, ios, swift, мобильная-разработка

Выучил Swift написал приложение. Все хорошо работает и функционирует, но есть нужда запустить его на Android. Как это можно делать без переписывания с нуля?

Answer (score 2):

Архитектура этих двух систем отличается чуть более, чем полностью. Так что в лоб нажатием пары кнопок проблему не решить. Задача не самая простая, но вполне решаемая. Придется переписать код полностью, все таки языки разные, может есть какие-то инструменты для частичной автоматизации процесса, но лишь частичной. На моем опыте самое сложное это gui, если с бизнесс-логикой, как правило, отличия не сильные и в основном синтаксические, то вьюшки со сложным поведением могут работать принципиально по разному. В общем, ничего другого, кроме как закатать рукава, погрузиться в андроид и воспроизвести весь свой код на java/kotlin вам, скорее всего, не предложат.

Есть всякие xamarin'ы, flutter'ы и прочие react native'ы, в которых вы один раз написали приложение и собрали под все платформы, но каждый из них использует свой язык, свои классы и даже свои парадигмы, которые отличаются от "родных" андроидовских или яблочных. Соответственно, если вы начали писать на них изначально - вы сэкономите силы на переводе на другую платформу. Но если уже есть проект на свифте перевести его на андроидовский родной SDK не сложнее, чем на какой-либо кросплатформенный фреймворк.